# Условие if в цикле for на каждый цикл для словаря в Python

Tags: python

Учу Python, Хочу написать скрипт для гадания на Таро.

Есть значения карт в словаре, где ключ - это позиция в раскладе для каждой карты.

Я понял как рандомно вывести карты из списка, но не пойму, что нужно сделать, чтобы при первом цикле for выводился ключ: "1", при втором - ключ "2" и так далее. Как это реализовать при помощи if, else?

```
import random

mag = {1: 'Маг говорит, всё хорошо', 2: 'Маг говорит, всё плохо!'}
shut = {1: 'Шут говорит, всё хорошо', 2: 'Шут говорит, всё плохо!'}
jritsa = {1: 'Жрица говорит, всё хорошо', 2: 'Жрица говорит, всё плохо!'}
emperor = {1: 'Император говорит, всё хорошо', 2: 'Император говорит, всё плохо!'}

tarot = [mag, shut, jritsa, emperor]

for i in random.sample(tarot, 2):
    if i:    
        print('Значение карты на 1-ой позиции:', i.get(1))
    else:    
        print('Значение карты на 2-ой позиции:', i.get(2))
```

Сейчас в коде просто выводятся карты по первому ключу в словаре.

Comment: Приведите пример результата, который Вы хотите получить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант: Меняем словари на кортежи:

```
mag = ("mag say good", "mag say bad")
```

и т.д.

```
sample_length = 2
sample = random.sample(tarot, sample_length)
for i in range(sample_length):
   print("Card value:", sample[i][i%2])
```

Вообще, Вам нужно просто проверять четность очередной итерации, поэтому вам нужен цикл со счетчиком, `i%2` - остаток от деления на 2, этим и занимается.

Comment: А если значений не два, а пять? Тогда проверка по чётности не подходит.

Comment: @АлександрЛевашов прекрасно подходит. Индекс значения остается равным `i % 5`.

Comment: Спасибо огромное!